# Disable Next/Prev on iPhone using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

Is it possible to disable the Next/Prev in iPhone using JS or JQuery?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering why you'd want to disable basic browser functionality.

Comment: @Suresh. I don't have a working code for that but when adding text field or List/Menu field that Next/Prev button automatically appear on iPhone, though it was a phone feature, I'm wondering if there's an option to disable that. 

The GO button work perfectly and the form will not submit using this script.

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('input').keypress(function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if ( (code==13) || (code==10) || (code==9))
            {
    jQuery(this).blur();
    return false;
            }
        }
    });

});

Comment: @Matt S. Because I need to track the event where the user click on the field. :)

Comment: What about users that cannot click, such as people using screen readers? Why can't you track whether a field is focused?

Comment: Also I need to prevent the user to navigate on the next page by using that Next/Prev button, let say I have a multi-step page using JQuery and I don't want them to proceed on the next step by hitting that button unless they click the Continue button.

1st page = text field + continue button
2nd Page = Combination of text and menu/list field + continue button
3rd page = text + submit

Comment: any help on this? :(